# Magento media/js folder filled up with 500kb js files each minute

Tags: javascript

Our magento/media/js folder is being populated with js files sometimes 4-6 times a minute. We just checked and there were 10Gb worth of files in there.

Cron only runs each 5 minutes.

We have turned off our FPC, our CDN and looked everywhere. No idea where to look next.

What could possibly cause this behaviour? The contents of the js file is just the basic js files.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS combine is probably the likely culprit.

Disable all JS combine extensions, including the native tool and 3rd party plugins like Fooman Speedster.

Comment: I actually did that prior to your answer and indeed the creating of these files stopped after i turned off the combine js option in the default configuration settings. Any downside to this being turned off speedwise? Any idea why this happens and how to prevent it from happening once we turn it back on? Cheers!

Comment: If you keep getting new merged JS files it sounds like you have lots of different possible JS file combinations. Or alternatively some process is constantly updating the files timestamp making Magento believe it needs to create a new file.

Comment: The js files are almost identical. They are gone now since we turned it off, however i have no clue what process would actually check for this, except maybe the FPC extension.

Comment: Don't bother turning it on. Your site will be faster without. Individually, the files increase the number of requests, but they can be cached by the browser, so there are no further subsequent requests. But combined, means that the JS is potentially different and thus redownloaded on every page. Keep it disabled.